# asp login in bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net, authentication, bootstrap-modal

I am a beginner to asp.net. I am currently working on a school project and I am using bootstrap modals for login and register. I am using the login and create user wizard and they work fine if i use them in a normal webform but the moment i insert them dynamically in my modal and press the button I get an error (
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
)

```
<form id="formLogin" runat="server">

    <%-- Modal --%>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" CssClass="modal-title">Log in</asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <asp:Login ID="Login2" runat="server" CssClass="User" DestinationPageUrl="~/Login/Home.aspx">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="User Name"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Login" ErrorMessage="Please enter an User Name" CssClass="error">Please enter an User Name</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                                TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Login" ErrorMessage="Please enter a password" CssClass="error">Please enter a password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                Don't have an account!
                            <%--Pressing the link will take us to the desired modal by using a javascript function --%>
                                <a href="javascript:$('#myModal .modal-content').load('Modals/modalDefaultRegister.aspx',function(e){$('#myModal').modal('show');});">Register here</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" class="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="Login" Text="Log in" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  />
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>

            </asp:Login>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

This is the script I use to show the modal and also clear it after use since I use it also  for the register

```
 <script>
    $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal:not(.local-modal)", function (e) {
        $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
    });

</script>
```

I use this button 
`<asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Modals/modalDefaultRegister.aspx">
                                    Register
                                </asp:LinkButton>`
 
in the main window to show the modal.
 Any ideas on where the problem is and how can I solve it?
Thank you

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @Aristos I hope this is enough to understand what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 suggests that you are submitting the form into a wrong url. I looked at the destination url and it is "~/login/home.apsx" that doesn't look normal.

Check your login url and most likely, it should have been ~/account/login.aspx". Look at the directory project and find the relative path for it.

Comment: Yes I am aware of what the error suggests. And as I said If I use it on a normal page it works great. But I am using a bootstrap modal and I load it in dynamically. And then de error occurs and actually requests the formLogin url.